# The remove button is not functioning

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In my jQuery, I have a button that is used to create the remove button:

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" id=\"remove\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Remove\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
});
```

However, when I add a remove button manually using the PHP instead of jQuery

```html
<div class='fieldwrapper' id=<? echo "field".$counter ?>
    <input type='button' id='remove' class='btn' value='Remove'>
</div>
```

I have checked if the fieldwrapper `id` is not overlapped, so why does it not work? Thank you.

### Updated:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#config").validate();

    $('#id').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#configField div").length + 1;
        var label = $("<label>Field Name:</label>");
        var labelType = $("<label>Field Type:</label>");
        var labelReq = $("<label>Require:</label>");
        var labelTag = $("<label>Tag:</label>");
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"Name" + intId + "\" class=\"required\" />");
        var fTag = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"Tag" + intId + "\" class=\"required\" />");
        var fReq = $("<select  class=\"required\" name=\"Req" + intId + "\" ><option selected=\"\" value=\"\">Please Select</option><option value=\"1\">Yes</option><option value=\"0\">No</option></select>");
        var fType = $("<select  class=\"required\" name=\"Type" + intId + "\"  ><option selected=\"\" value=\"\">Please Select</option><option value=\"txt\">Text</option><option value=\"int\">Numbers</option><option value=\"bool\">Boolean</option></select>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" id=\"remove\" class=\"btn remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");

        fieldWrapper.append('<br>');
        fieldWrapper.append(label);
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append('<br>');
        fieldWrapper.append(labelType);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append('<br>');
        fieldWrapper.append(labelReq);
        fieldWrapper.append(fReq);
        fieldWrapper.append('<br>');
        fieldWrapper.append(labelTag);
        fieldWrapper.append(fTag);
        fieldWrapper.append('<br>');
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#configField").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

    $('.remove').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

#### PHP:

```php
<div class='fieldwrapper' id=<? echo "field".$counter ?>
    <input type='button' id='remove' class='btn remove' value='Remove'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only initiating the remove button functionality after clicking "#add". By declaring it apart from the internal function, and specifying "delegate('click', " you will ensure that every .remove element will always delete its parent

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" id=\"remove\" class=\"btn remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");

    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
});


$('.remove').delegate('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but can i use id instead of class? eg. $('#remove').live('click', function() {

Comment: Not if you plan on having multiple remove buttons. Perhaps it "might" work, but being that you will have multiple remove buttons, using a class works much more effectively

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the.live() method is deprecated. Use.on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use.delegate() in preference to.live().

Comment: You don't need a unique ID for every element, you'll see that I added remove after the btn on the input element. class=\"btn remove\". @j08691 I've updated the example to use on(). I guess I'm becoming old school :(

Comment: @BryanMoyles - its good to use the newer .on() function however I believe your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Please have a look on updated question, it works for the php added remove button, however, it do not work for the remove button that is generate by #add button.

Comment: Perharps its synatx problem as i use live instead of on and work as my expection

Comment: Sorry, instead of on(), try delegate(). I've updated my example

Comment: @BryanMoyles - As with .live(), as of jQuery 1.7 .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. The problem wasn't that you were using .on(), that was correct, however your syntax was just off.